# How do I convert a Rust string to a C string?

Tags: rust, ffi

I'm using Rust's FFI to call LLVM. Here's a minimal working example, based on the [example provided with the library](https://bitbucket.org/tari/llvm-sys.rs/src/d36872052b73ab5e2f99eec09f82b1fc1c4f0c71/examples/nop-function.rs?at=default).

```
extern crate llvm_sys as llvm;

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let module = llvm::core::LLVMModuleCreateWithName(b"nop\0".as_ptr() as *const _);
        llvm::core::LLVMDumpModule(module);
        llvm::core::LLVMDisposeModule(module);
    }
}
```

This works, and valgrind reports no errors. However, I want to use Rust strings in my code, so I wrote this:

```
extern crate llvm_sys as llvm;
use std::ffi::CString;

/// Convert a Rust string to a C char pointer.
fn cstr(s: &str) -> *const i8 {
    let cstring = CString::new(s).unwrap();
    cstring.to_bytes_with_nul().as_ptr() as *const _
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let module = llvm::core::LLVMModuleCreateWithName(cstr("nop"));
        llvm::core::LLVMDumpModule(module);
        llvm::core::LLVMDisposeModule(module);
    }
}
```

However, valgrind now reports:

```
==7147== ERROR SUMMARY: 6 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Is this because `cstring` is being dropped when `cstr` returns? Since `cstr` is safe, why does the compiler not complain about `cstr`? What's the correct way to pass arbitrary Rust strings to C libraries?

Comment: Creating a dangling raw pointer is safe in rust -- dereferencing it or calling ffi is not. This conspires to have forced you use `unsafe` at least once to produce memory unsafe code, like in the example.

Comment: Yep, and the "unsafe" code might just be the big chunk of C code that you pass that raw pointer to! :-)